# Getting the Locale short code

Tags: java, locale

In Java it is easy enough to get the default Locale, but is there a way to get the short code that you see so often in websites such as lang=en or lang=zh

I need to send to information to a website but need the short code so the response will be in the correct language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Locale.getLanguage()` method ([API Link](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29))

> Returns the language code for this locale, which will either be the empty string or a lowercase ISO 639 code.

ISO-639 is the standard for two-letter language codes. See [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) for the list.